# Save output image of CNN model

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, tensor

I made a CNN model for edge detection task. It worked fine and I can see good results through the Feature maps. the problem is I'm using 4 filters in each convolutional layer, so the output is going to be an image with 4 channels but I need the image to be saved as a 3 channels to work with it later, here an example of the code I used:

```
#Feed image to model:
output = model(img) #input size (1, 3, 224, 224)
#convert output tensor to numpy
fimg = output.detach().cpu().numpy()   
#get rid of the single batch dimension 
f2img = fimg.squeeze(0)
#swap axes to (13, 13, 4)
f2img = fimg.transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

it's gonna be saved as (13,13,4) but I need it as (13, 13, 3). If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Use autoencoder for this task or change model to output 3 channels or for this split to 4 images of `(13, 13, 1)`.

Comment: you can save it as an `RGBA` image that has 4 channels.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Convert Image array RGBA to PIL Image object

   from PIL Import Image

   img_rgba = Image.fromarray(img_rgba)
2. RGBA Image object to RGB

   img_rgb = img_rgba.convert('RGB')
3. Back to np.ndarray

   img_rgb = np.array(img_rgb)

Note : If your Image was in RBGA format instead of RGBA, you will need an additional step to convert it to RGB from RBG.

img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)